# How to edit BIOS setting in order to boot from Windows 7 install DVD from Ubuntu

Tags: boot

Forgive me if this question is duplicate. I've seen threads related to this post I am about to write but they didn't fit a problem domain I am facing.

I have a year old laptop bought for my son. It came with Windows 8 but soon I decided to move away from it and install Ubuntun. I don't remember the exact version but I think version 14.x.x.

Being a newbie to Ubuntu, I never got booting the laptop correctly. I had to press F10(?) quickly and multiple times otherwise booting OS fails. I never understood why/how behind this matter. I found a quick answer from here (Thanks!) so that my son can start the system and move on.

Now we decided to go back to Windows OS so I bought Windows 7 install CD but he is having trouble to install it. He and I thought if you put the install CD then re-start the system, install process would kick it in but that doesn't happen according to him.

I have to see myself exactly what he is running into tonight but it sounds like the system was trying to read from the CD (noise from CD drive) then nothing happens (noise downs also).

Eventually my son just got into Ubuntu system, searched through a file system. He was looking for CD icon but didn't find it.

I am newbie to Ubuntu. Is it something about mounting a CD we have to do?

I wonder time has come to fix broken booting process first even before installing Windows OS.

Someone (Linux expert) I've talked to said something about GRUB but I had a time hard understanding it.....

I'd appreciate your advice and tips on this matter.

Comment: There should be a key combo which you would press to select the boot menu, which lets you select whether to boot from CD/DVD drive(a Windows Disk currently) or from the Disk (Ubuntu). Most of the time it is the <kbd>Del</kbd> key or __F12__ key. Once you boot from DVD, you can proceed the normal installation procedure. Keep a guide handy doing this.

Comment: Thanks to all of your advice. It turns out that I had to touch BIOS setting, make sure boot from CD-ROM (set it as first option) and change UEIF to legacy then the system booted from DVD (windows 7). To be honest with you, I don't know why I have to switch from UEIF to legacy. Read about it but I never understood....